# Can I set a property value with Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I know the name of a property in my C# class. Is it possible to use reflection to set the value of this property?

For example, say I know the name of a property is `string propertyName = "first_name";`. And there actaully exists a property called `first_name`. Can I set it using this string?

Comment: Is it a static property?

Comment: I would rename the question to: "Is it possible to use reflection to set the value of a property?" And answer is: Yes, it is possible. You can do it.

Comment: @Snowbear It wouldn't allow me to use Question in the title, and needed to be 15 chars. If you dont like the title, then change it.

Comment: @BoltClock No, it is not a static property

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, you can use reflection - just fetch it with [`Type.GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) (specifying binding flags if necessary), then call [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx) appropriately. Sample:

```
using System;

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        var property = typeof(Person).GetProperty("Name");
        property.SetValue(p, "Jon", null);
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name); // Jon
    }
}
```

If it's not a public property, you'll need to specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` in the `GetProperty` call.