# Setting a property generically

Tags: c#, reflection, mvvm-light

I have a model class that contains a range of properties. I am writing an MVVM Light service that will allow me to directly assign those properties which means I need to create both an interface and service.

Is there a way that I can do something like this

```
myService.SetProperty(propertyName, value)
```

and

```
var n = myService.GetProperty(propertyName)
```

where `propertyName` is always a string, but using reflection the correct property is found within the model class and set or read?

Comment: Yes this is possible ... ^^ Can you please post the code you have written for the moment and explain what kind of problem you encounter ?

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to see [setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value).

or [can-i-set-a-property-value-with-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718792/can-i-set-a-property-value-with-reflection)

or [PropertyInfo.SetValue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.