# Copy data from a List of object to a different Object in C#

Tags: c#, .net

My goal is to reduce the code and avoid having to add conditions when my passed list of object gets longer, it can be up to 100+ fields as the project progresses. I have an object of type MyObject

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string fininstId { get; set; }
    public string paymentMethod { get; set; }
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
    public string cardExpiry { get; set; }
    public string cardCVC { get; set; }
    public string AcctName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string mode { get; set; }
}
```

another one of type Response

```
public class Response
{
    public Response();

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and I need all of the data contained in *dataList* below to be copied to *MyObject*, knowing that the name of the fields are going to be the same in both *MyObject* and *dataList*.

```
List<Response> dataList = new List<Response>();

/*...populating dataList here ...*/

MyObject request = new MyObject();

foreach (var item in dataList)
{
    switch (item.Title)
    {
        case "cardNumber":
            request.cardNumber = item.Value;
            break;
        case "cardExpiry":
            request.cardExpiry = item.Value;
            break;
        case "cardCVC":
            request.cardCVC = item.Value;
            break;
        case "fininstId":
            request.fininstId = item.Value;
            break;
        case "paymentMethod":
            request.paymentMethod = item.Value;
            break;
        case "AcctName":
            request.AcctName = item.Value;
            break;
        case "Password":
            request.Password = item.Value;
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway it can be done dynamically?

Comment: You can use Reflection to reduce the amount of code to something that just matches the Title string to a property name, but it won't perform near as well.

Comment: You can [use reflection to find a property that matches the string in `Title`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718792).  The conditions you need to account for are: "what if the property does not exist?"  and "How do I handle type conversion?".  Neither of those has a trivial answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)  and [`InvokeMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember(v=vs.110).aspx) method

For example:

```
Response item = new Response();
item.Title = "Password";
item.Value = "value";

MyObject request = new MyObject();
request.GetType().InvokeMember(item.Title,
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
Type.DefaultBinder, request, new[] {item.Value} );
```

Or using [`GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) & [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx)

```
var property = typeof(MyObject).GetProperty(item.Title);
property.SetValue(request, item.Value, null);
```