# How can we reach an instance and assign its value?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-type-argument

I have `foreach` code block in a method, I'm using this many places.

"Title" is a String type property of "UsefulLinks" class which I mention "Before".
But I want to assign that property with my String variable which is fieldName. How can we reach an instance and assign its value?

Before:

```
        foreach (var item in vm.UsefulLinks)
        {
            item.Title = usefullLinkTranslations
                .LastOrDefault(t => t.FieldName == fieldName)
                ?.Value;
        }
```

After:

```
        foreach (var item in vm.UsefulLinks)
        {
            item.["fieldName"]= usefullLinkTranslations
                .LastOrDefault(t => t.FieldName == fieldName)
                ?.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either build a switch statement for each property you want to support:

```
foreach (var item in vm.UsefulLinks)
{
    var fieldValue = usefullLinkTranslations.LastOrDefault(t => t.FieldName == fieldName)?.Value;

    switch (fieldName)
    {
        case "Title":
            item.Title = fieldValue;
            break;
        case "Name":
            item.Name = fieldValue;
            break;
        // ...
    }

}
```

Or [use reflection to assign the property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718792/can-i-set-a-property-value-with-reflection).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection (@smile mentioned) like this;

```
var type = typeof(UsefulLinks);
foreach (var item in vm.UsefulLinks)
{
    type.GetProperty(fieldName) // GetField for fields
         .SetValue(
             item, 
             usefullLinkTranslations
                 .LastOrDefault(t => t.FieldName == fieldName)
                 ?.Value
         );
}
```