# Is there any way to set object value like object[attribute]?

Tags: c#

I am trying to map datatable row to object. (C#)

I have Datatable like this.

```
|----|------|---------|
|ID  | Name | Address |
|----|------|---------|
| 1  | Tom  | USA     |
|----|------|---------|
| 2  | Tim  | AU      |
|----|------|---------|
```

And I have Object

```
Contact {
int ID,
String Name,
String Address
}
```

And I want to map dynamically like

```
Contact contact = new Contact();

foreach (var row in rows) {
   foreach(var col in table.Columns)
     contact[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnaName]
}
```

Like Javascript, Is there any way to set value in object by columnName?

Comment: Reflection, or automapper (maybe), or Dapper (maybe)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set a property value with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718792/can-i-set-a-property-value-with-reflection)

Comment: So which row means 1st or 2nd row your want to map to Contact object? or you want all the rows to list of contact object

Comment: @John, automapper is very slow, what is it for? Reflection, Emitmapper, mapster

Comment: [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56857) is an example how to map DataTable to object.

Comment: @pasha I was suggesting a number of ways to do it. Perhaps you didn't see the other suggestions? I'm not sure what _"what is it for"_ means? If you say it's slow, surely you already understand its function?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Contact class like this:

```
    public class Contact
    {
        private int ID;
        private string Name;
        private string Address;

        public Contact(int _ID, string _Name, string _Address)
        {
            ID = _ID;
            Name = _Name;
            Address = _Address;
        }
    }
```

After that you can create a contact like this: `Contact c = new Contact(1, "Tom", "Berlin");`

You can wrap your foreach arround it and use your DataRow to fill the Contact.

like so:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Fill this table            

        foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Contact c = new Contact(row["ID"], row["Name"], row["Address"]);
        }
```