# Can I set multiple List Item property values with Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

In continuation to: [Can I set a property value with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718792/can-i-set-a-property-value-with-reflection), I have a challenge-

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ListItem> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

List Selections has 2 Items
1.

```
{
Text = 'Business Management', Value = 'Course 1', Selected = 'true'
}
```

2. 

```
{
Text = 'Network Management', Value = 'Course 2', Selected = 'false'
}
```

How do I assign the Selections to Courses property of the Student class?

Comment: What is *List Selections*? Do you need to convert one of those Items to a `ListItem` and add it to the `Courses` List? Why do you think you need Reflection for this?

Comment: ‘Selections’ is the name of the List containing the above two ListItems

Comment: I want to add the ListItem with Selected = true to Courses.

Comment: The reason I need reflection is because like Student class, there are a good number of classes and depending on this, I would like to look for property.name and assign value. Right now, I am able to do it for text boxes. I want to be able to do it with a ListBox as well

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the question. *What is Selection* is asking what kind of items that list contains. Is it `Selections<ListItem>`? The same `ListItem` object of `Courses`? Or is it something else? Can you post the class definitions of the objects that these lists contain?

Comment: List<ListItem> Selections = new List<ListItem>(); using (Entities DB = new Entities){ Selections = DB.StudentSelections.Select(x => new ListItem{ Text = x.CourseName , Value = x.CourseId, Selected = x.OptInStatus }) }

Comment: This is how I’m extracting the List details from the database. The object type is simply a list of ListItem as per the above —Vishwa

Answer (score 0):

To answer to this, I have found that .net automatically identifies the Property as List and I have been able to loop through and assign values using the property.SetValue() method