# Dynamically setting LINQ field names during execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table in my database that defines the structure of the other tables.  I want to be able to reuse code based on field type, but have no idea how to dynamically set the field to be used.

In my code, I want to be able to pass a function a table name, field name, and field value.  The function will look up the field datatype and through a switch statement, pass the field name and field value to that case.

Right now, I am using the switch statement based on field name and then hardcoding everything in.
This leads to A LOT of cases:

```
switch (passedfieldname) {
   case "tag4":
       var item = _context.Table.Where(i => i.Id == 13).SingleOrDefault();
       item.Tag4 = passedfieldvalue;
       _context.SubmitChanges();
       break;
}
```

What I would LIKE to be able to do is:

```
switch (fieldtype) {
   case "string":
       var item = _context.Table.Where(i => i.Id == 13).SingleOrDefault();
       item.passedfieldname = passedfieldvalue;
       _context.SubmitChanges();
       break;
}
```

IS there a ***simple*** solution to this?

Thanks for any help or even pointing me to the right documentation to read up on.

Comment: I assume `item.passedfieldname` is pseudo code for some arbitrary property/field identified by a string variable?  If so, you should read up on reflection.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718792/can-i-set-a-property-value-with-reflection

Comment: @Jack A  That was exactly what I was looking for !!!!  Thank you